# Can we migrate AWS redshift from one VPC to another without any downtime?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-vpc

I understand that if we want to migrate redshift from one VPC to another we need to take a snapshot and restore it. We have around 50 GB of data in our redshift, which I guess will take around 30-50 mins.
During this time, there will be a downtime for the apps using the DB. Is there any way we can reduce the downtime?

Answer (score 1):

There is no downtime when creating a snapshot, and your redshift will still be running and accessible.

The only thing recommended though to disable any data load during the snapshot to make sure your data is identical and up to date.

Comment: by downtime i mean disabling the data load during that time. Is there a way I reduce the time, if my redshift has around 500 gb of data .